# Encoding Problems with maven

Tags: maven, encoding, mysql

I have a strange encoding problem. I have written a little java program to process mysqldump files and applies a kind of search and replace. When use this program directly from the command line (`java -jar …`) and import the result using the phpmyadmin interface everything works fine. The input file was downloaded from another phpmyadmin interface.

I try to automate the usage in a maven pom.xml. Therefore I am going two steps:

1. dump the database from the server with this code:

[maven-exec plugin cofiguration](http://pastebin.com/4X9tDhe2)

Problem: If I process the file created by maven, some mistakes comes to happen.

1. importing the processed file with maven:

[maven-mysql plugin configuration](http://pastebin.com/r5RL4UQ1)

Problem: Even more mistakes come to happen.

So I guess that this is an encoding problem, since the program I wrote assumes that all input files are UTF-8 encoded. But to be honest, I have no idea why everything works fine on the commandline, but not with maven. Any Ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you started your java programm with correct encoding `java -jar ...`? Furthermore where is the assumption having UTF-8 encoding ?

Comment: The java program assumes that the input-file is utf-8 encoded and spits out a new file which is also utf-8 encoded (that is tested). The program itself is written like any other java program,no special character encoding was applied to the source files.

Comment: If no encoding is given than the default of the JVM is used which dependency on the platform you are on. On which os are you?

Comment: Based that i only see excerpt of your converting string you might have missed to set the encoding for the sql-maven-plugin.

Comment: I did set it. But as i am going on in finding the reason, i guess I am wrong in assuming that it is an encoding problem. It looks like that the output of mysqldump is different to the export of phpmyadmin, I need to do some more research but I am quite sure that this difference is most significant on escape sequences, what could break my program. I have not known that… But thanks for your help!!